# My local MongoDB instance is not saving data via Express and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So this is working in the console but not writing to the db. When I restart the server the data just resets. It's reading from the db just fine, just not saving. I'm running the mongo shell and clearly pulling data from it, just not updating or creating data like I want. Here's the code in my server.js file:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app = express();

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/food');


    //Allow all requests from all domains & localhost
    app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET");
      next();
    });

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


    var usersSchema = new Schema({
      _id: String,
      id: String,
      vote: Number
    });

    var bkyes = mongoose.model('bkyes', usersSchema);


    app.post('/bkyes', function(req, res, next) {

    bkyes.find({}, function(err, foundObject) {
      console.log(foundObject);  //Print pre-update
      var found = foundObject[0];
      found.vote = req.body.vote; //Passing in the number 5 here(was -1 before)
      found.save(function(err) {

          console.log(foundObject); //Print post-update
        });
      });
    });


    app.listen(3000);

    /*
    The console.log pre-update:
    [ { _id: '582b2da0b983b79b61da3f9c', id: 'Burger King', vote: -1 } ]
                                                                   ^
    The console.log post-update:
    [ { _id: '582b2da0b983b79b61da3f9c', id: 'Burger King', vote: 5 } ]
                                                                  ^
    However this data does NOT write to the db and just resets when you restart the server!!
    */
```

Comment: Check you `req.body.vote`, is it a number?

Comment: It is, It's being passed in from the front-end. As you can see in that comment section on the bottom, it's updating the Mongo BSON, just not saving it to the db. When I check the shell it hasn't actually been written.

Comment: use findOneAndUpdate() rather then find and then save

Comment: Any chance of helping me out with an example? I looked around and am at an absolute stand still here, going on 5 hours and cannot get this going.. the Mongo docs are a bit arcane when it comes to findOneAndUpdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `foundObjects`is not effect by `save()` function in anyway, so the logs is kind of useless.

I don't know why you want to find every documents in `bkyes` and get the first one out. You often find a document with some conditions, and it is usually the `_id` field.

Anyway, here is an example with `findOneAndUpdate()`:

```
bkyes
  .findOneAndUpdate({
    // Conditions
    _id: '00001'
  }, {
    // Set which fields to update
    vote: 5 
  })
  .exec(function(err, foundObject) {
    if (err) {
      // Error handler here
    }

    // Do something when update successfully
  });
```

**NOTES:** `foundObject` is the object **before** the update.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. In this video at 4:16 the guy uses foundObject.save() successfully so that's where I'm getting it from. https://youtu.be/5_pvYIbyZlU?t=4m16s Also how I'm finding the value is what I'll deal with next, I'd just like to see it saving before that. Let me know your thoughts, I appreciate your input.

Comment: In that video, that guy use `findOne()` which will return an object or null while you use `find()` which will always return an array. Mongoose `save()` method only work on model.

Comment: Ok I'm using 'findOneAndUpdate()' now and logging 'foundObject' now returns null.. I could have the syntax wrong for 'findOneAndUpdate()', I'll dig into the docs and if you have any other suggestions please fire at will.

Comment: Hey thanks! Your help got this working for me, very kind of you to help my friend.